# I would like to use haskell to translate my DSL into R

Tags: haskell, code-generation, dsl

I would like to use haskell to translate my DSL into R. I mean I want to first parse my DSL, then generate R code from it. I know there are DSLs implemented in haskell, but they all assume that the target language of compiling the DSL to is haskell code.

Please note that the end product should be generated R code. So it's not simply a DSL implemented in haskell, but a DSL that generates non-haskell code; in my case R-code.

Pseudo code for the DSL can be similar to this:

```
d =_ a o b o c
# ==> 
d <- function(x) a( b( c( x))) # generated R code



f1 a b =_ a + b
# ==> 
f1 <- function(a, b) a + b # generated R code



f2 =_ \x. a (\y. y + y) (x * x) (\z. z / z)
# ==>
f2 <- function(x) a( function(y) y + y, x * x, function(z) z / z) # generated R code



put_ "abc " "def"
# ==>
print(put("abc ", "def ", sep="")) # generated R code
```

Comment: You might want to rephrase that question into the form "I would like to use haskell to translate my DSL into R. I thought about using parsec, but is there a simpler way that avoids writing everything from first principles?" To avoid the _library recommendations are forbidden_ close rule.

Comment: There are many DSLs in written in Haskell that generate code in other languages than Haskell. From the examples you've provided it looks like you have a small functional language (it has lambdas) that you want to translate into R. Maybe you could start by looking at interpreters for the Lambda Calculus and replace the interpretation function with a translator function that generates R.

Comment: @stephentetley just to be curious, can you name a few DSPLs that generate non-haskell code? From my memory I can only think of DSPLs that generate CSS/HTML.

Comment: @mrsteve. The primary example is Conal Elliott's Pan which generated C code for image processing. Conal later generated shader code with Vertigo. There are various DSL that generate Cuda (Obsidian, Accelerate, Barracuda). Sigrlami mentions Copilot which generated C via Tom Hawkins's Atom (it might not use Atom these days). There are hardware languages like Lava, etc. that generate VHDL or Verilog as well as SAT solver "proofs".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a small **compiler**, that will read your DSL's files and generate R code. There are several compilers that you can look at, to understand how to write it.

Haskell to C : [Jhc](http://repetae.net/computer/jhc/)([AJHC](http://ajhc.metasepi.org/)), [Copilot](http://leepike.github.io/Copilot/)
Haskell to JS: [Fay](https://github.com/faylang/fay/wiki),[Roy](https://github.com/puffnfresh/roy)

There are also compilers to hardware languages. I'd recommend take a look at Fay for references

Comment: @mrsteve I also have proprietary library, that generates vhdl code. Contact with me.Maybe, I can help you with your project in a specific way, there are basic rules for developing such kind of software.